# Bootstrap jQgrid multiselect not working with filter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

[image]

Implemented custom filter based on outside jqgrid.When we apply filter and multiselect the records.Records are not selected properly.I have enabled jqgrid **multiselect:true**.

How can we handle these issue.
Any help on these guys.!
On entering text in search text box jqgrid will filter the records.
below code for filtering:

```
function FilterJobBySearchTerm() {
var searchString = $("#txtBoxApprovedCpSearch").val();

//  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
var f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };

//  Rules to specify column where to apply filters
f.rules.push({ field: "JobName", op: "cn", data: searchString });
f.rules.push({ field: "PM", op: "cn", data: searchString });
f.rules.push({ field: "JobNumber", op: "cn", data: searchString });
f.rules.push({ field: "CPNumber", op: "cn", data: searchString });
f.rules.push({ field: "TotalCost", op: "cn", data: searchString });
f.rules.push({ field: "TotalPrice", op: "cn", data: searchString });

var grid = $('#accountantApprovedCPgrid');
grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length > 0;
$.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
}
```

Comment: If we navigate through pagination.also the multiselect checkbox does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

I got it.jgrid key column should contain unique value then only multiple select works.